# I get an error when trying to receive data from the server in a python UDP socket using recvfrom()

Tags: python, sockets, networking, client

I get the error message: "OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied" for the line: data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)

Client Code:

```
def receive():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(data.decode('ascii'))
    sock.close()
    return data

send('Connection Made')
while True: receive()
```

It sends 'Connection Made' to the Server but then gives the error on receive()

Comment: maybe missing sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))?

Comment: I thought you only use bind for the server?

Comment: Bind the socket to address. The socket must not already be bound... the receiver has to listen the address, without any address is little difficult